# Separating some part of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2m by 2 matrix called A  and a 2 by  m matrix called B. Let's name the product of A by B, C:
    C= A*B;

which C is a 2m by m matrix. I want to find matrix F which contains some parts of C. F is a m by 2 matrix and contains elements C(1,1), C(2,1), C(3,2),C(4,2),C(5,3), C(6,3),...C(2m-1,m), C(2m,m).
For example, consider

```
A = [0,2;1,3;4,7;8,3;4,5;1,2]
B=[1,4,6;5,7,3]
C=A*B;
```

In this case:

```
F=[C(1,1),C(2,1);C(3,2),C(4,2);C(5,3),C(6,3)]
```

But I like to find F without calculating all elements of C. Because I think calculating all elements of C would be time wasting for large values of m. Could anyone suggest a way to find F in general case?

Comment: Could anyone understand the question?

Comment: I'm sure the one who downvoted to this question can not understand it even!

Comment: Two comments: (1) Your desired output is actually `m x 2` not `2 x m`.  (2) The column indices go up to `m`, not `m / 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Indexing:

```
F = [C(1:2*m+2:end);C(2:2*m+2:end)]'
```

To find `F` without calculating `C` you can instead use:

```
F=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) A(2*x-1:2*x,:)*B(:,x), 1:m,'uniformoutput',0))'
```

(You must set `m, A, and B` as defined in the question)

**Explanation:**
Each row of F is the transpose of the product of a submatrix in A and a column of B. For example, the first row in F is the transpose of:

```
A(1:2,:)*B(:,1)
```

The next row is the transpose of:

```
A(3:4,:)*B(:,2)
```

etc.

So this method only calculates the necessary values, by multiplying each column of B only by the corresponding submatrix of A and avoids calculating the unused values in C.

Comment: Is there anyway to find F without calculating all elements of C?

Comment: I think there should be. Could you update the question to include that and I'll check into it.

Comment: I did add it to the question.

Comment: sorry, which one is faster and more optimized? Your answer or rayryeng's?

Comment: @saranj it could depend on the size of the matrix because for such a small matrix you don't save much avoiding the multiplication. The indexing method I wrote first will by far outperform the other methods (using arrayfun or sparse) for matrices like the ones you gave in your questions.

Comment: But I want to use it for big matrices

Comment: For very large matrices, the method that avoids calculation of C will be fastest. If performance is an issue, you could then improve it even further by changing the arrayfun call to a for loop (make sure to preallocate F).